# Relatively Prime Numbers

Tags: c++, math, primes

How to make a function in c++ to determine if two entered numbers are relatively prime (no common factors)?
For example "1, 3" would be valid, but "2, 4" wouldn't.

Comment: [The Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: see Stein's Algorithm or Binary GCD. And, homework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Galvanised into action by Jim Clay's incautious comment, here is Euclid's algorithm in six lines of code:

```
bool RelativelyPrime (int a, int b) { // Assumes a, b > 0
  for ( ; ; ) {
    if (!(a %= b)) return b == 1 ;
    if (!(b %= a)) return a == 1 ;
  }
}
```

**Updated** to add: I have been out-obfuscated by [this answer from Omnifarious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016771/is-constexpr-really-needed/6476038#6476038), who programs the `gcd` function thus:

```
constexpr unsigned int gcd(unsigned int const a, unsigned int const b)
{
   return (a < b) ? gcd(b, a) : ((a % b == 0) ? b : gcd(b, a % b));
}
```

So now we have a three-line version of RelativelyPrime:

```
bool RelativelyPrime (int a, int b) { // Assumes a, b > 0
   return (a<b) ? RelativelyPrime(b,a) : !(a%b) ? (b==1) : RelativelyPrime (b, a%b);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "horrible" code style; I got goosebumps reading it.

Comment: +1 for horrible code style - it honors Euclid. Any simple, clear explanation of how it works is missing the pure genius of the astonishing theorem.

Answer (score 6):

One of the many algorithms for computing the [Greatest Common Denominator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: As referenced in that Wikipedia article under "Further Reading", Knuth's AOCP v.2 (Seminumerical Algorithms) has good analysis of the efficiency of several approaches.