# how can I create a template from string literal?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I want to create a template class from string literal:
create_eq("abcdefg") get  IEqual<'a','b','c','d','e'>
but ISO C++11's User-defined literals only support integer-literal and ﬂoating-literal :

```
template<char... Chars>
  IEqual<Chars...>  operator "" _suffix()
  {

    return {};
  }
    auto a=3423134_suffix;//yes
    auto b="abcdef"_suffix;//error!
```

I try

```
using Char=int;
template<Char...ARGS>
class IEqual
{
public:

};

template<unsigned... I> struct Index{};
template<unsigned N, unsigned... I>
struct GenIndex : GenIndex<N-1, N-1, I...>{};
template<unsigned... I>
struct GenIndex<0, I...> : Index<I...>{};
template<unsigned I>
constexpr Char pos(const char*a)
{
    return a[I];
}
 template<unsigned...I>
   constexpr auto eq(Index<I...> ,const char*a)
       ->decltype(IEqual<(pos<I>(a))...>())// this error 
    {
        return {};
    }
    template<unsigned N>
   constexpr auto eq(const char(&a)[N])
   ->decltype(eq(GenIndex<N>{},a))
   {
       return eq(GenIndex<N>{},a);
   }
```

so how can I do it?

Comment: Hating to be the bringer of sad news, but.... [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547852/string-literals-not-allowed-as-non-type-template-parameters) But I think you already knew that. Are you looking for work-arounds?

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, I'll be the [bearer of good news](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583022/c-can-a-macro-expand-abc-into-a-b-c/).

Comment: Also, for the record you can have user defined literals for `const char[N]`.

Comment: I want to write a Compile-time parser.now I have to write a run-time parser

Comment: @Rapptz the latter briefly eluded to at the end of the first answer in the first link, though I like your decl more (honestly makes more sense at least in my head).

Comment: "but ISO C++11's User-defined literals only support integer-literal and ﬂoating-literal" this is wrong. Check out this http://ideone.com/cEBUmX

Comment: @user1233963 my mean is "template<char... Chars>" Form.