# How to create a `std::integer_sequence` out of `__func__`?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I'm trying to create a function `foobar()` that can be used as...

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto x = foobar(__func__);
    // decltype(x) = std::integer_sequence<char, 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n'>
}
```

Any hints?

The code does **not** need to work on MSVC.

Comment: C++ has very limited introspection capabilities. You're going to have to wait if this is exactly what you want.

Comment: The "macro" `__func__` already expands to a `constexpr` `"main"`. This isn't an introspection problem.

Comment: C++11, C++14, C++17 or C++20?

Comment: @max66 At least 14, given `integer_sequence`.

Comment: @cigien - Good point.

Comment: @vinipsmaker, Fair enough. I guess what I was getting at is that you receive the array as a plain array. If you want to turn its contents into template arguments, you have to fit it into template-land from the get-go. Once you pass it as a regular parameter, it's already too late because parameters are not constant expressions. And then you have to deal with passing the local array as a template argument. Where I was going is that `foobar(reflexpr(main))` is an incredibly more doable process.

Comment: @Evg, What you're seeing is `__func__` passed to the macro and used in the context of the closure's `operator()`. `__func__` is a compile-time array rather than a preprocessor-time string literal.

Comment: @chris, got it, thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074039/8372853) appears to be a good option.

Comment: @cigien, thanks for the hint. It's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach that works with GCC and Clang without need for C++20 using the [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) language extension:

```
template<std::size_t n>
struct helper {
    const char(& s)[n];
    
    constexpr helper(const char(& str)[n]) : s(str)
    {}
    
    template<class Fn, std::size_t... is>
    static constexpr auto apply(Fn fn, std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        return fn(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, is>{}...);
    }

    template<class Fn>
    static constexpr auto apply(Fn fn) {
        return apply(fn, std::make_index_sequence<n - 1>{});
    }
};


#define arr_as_char_sequence(ARR)                                         \
    ({ constexpr helper my_helper(ARR); my_helper.apply([](auto... is)    \
          { return std::integer_sequence<char, my_helper.s[is]...>{}; }); });

void foo() {
    auto name = arr_as_char_sequence(__func__);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<
        decltype(name), std::integer_sequence<char, 'f', 'o', 'o'>>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/da57T1)

Comment: Beautiful. I like it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem I see is that passing `__func__` as a function argument

```
foobar(__func__);
```

I don't see a way to change the returned type of `foobar()` according the value of `__func__`.

Different if you pass `__func__` as template parameter, but `__func__` is a string literal, and a string literal (as far I know) can't be a template parameter before C++20.

But... if you accept a C++20 solution where `__func__` is passed as template parameter... I suppose you can write something as follows

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <std::size_t N>
struct bar
 {
   using index_type = std::make_index_sequence<N-1u>;
    
   std::array<char, N-1u> arr;
    
   template <std::size_t ... Is>
   constexpr bar (std::index_sequence<Is...>, char const (&a0)[N]) : arr{a0[Is]...}
    { }
    
   constexpr bar (char const (&a0)[N]) : bar{index_type{}, a0}
    { }
 };

template <bar b, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto baz (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 -> std::integer_sequence<char, b.arr[Is]...>
 { return {}; }

template <bar b>
constexpr auto foo () 
 { return baz<b>(typename decltype(b)::index_type{}); }

int main ()
{
  using target_type = std::integer_sequence<char, 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n'>;
    
  constexpr auto x = foo<__func__>();
    
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x), target_type const> );
}
```